# Организация архитектуры программы

Tags: java, ооп

У меня есть абстрактный класс

```
abstract class Parent
{

    private static AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong(0); 
    private long id=nextId.incrementAndGet(); // unique object id 
    private long in_id=0;
    private long out_id=0;

    protected long GetInId(){return this.in_id;}
    protected long GetOutId(){return this.out_id;}
    protected void SetInId(long in_id){this.in_id=in_id;}   //left index
    protected void SetOutId(long out_id){this.out_id=out_id;} //right index
}
```

Есть класс унаследованный от `Parent`

Каждый экземпляр класса унаследованного от `Parent`, имеет уникальный идентификатор
Переменные `in_id` и `out_id` нужны для того чтобы можно было связать между собой несколько объектов в "цепочку", (в дальнейшем нужно для определения порядка вызова некоторых методов этих объектов). Однако появилась проблема, для некоторых объектов in_id и out_id могут быть массивами, я назову дальше эти объекты "нестандартными"

В классе Parent есть много методов, которые нужны в этих нестандартных объектах и было бы логично унаследоваться от него, однако это не даст мне возможности сделать in_id и out_id массивами. Я вижу несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы:

1. Поля  in_id и out_id и методы GetInId(), GetOutId() убрать из абстрактного класса и перенести в наследники, но это дает много избыточного кода
2. Определить поля in_id и out_id массивами, но для объектов, где не требуется массив делать размер массива 1, но мне кажется это не самым хорошим стилем.
3. Создать еще 2 интерфейса с методами GetInId() и GetOutId(), которые будут возвращаться long и  long[] соответственно. И имплементировать их нужным классам
4. Создать 2 абстрактных класса `ParentSingleValue, ParentArrayValue` в них определить методы GetInId() и GetOutId(), чтобы они возвращали long и long[] соответственно и наследоваться их нужными классами

4 решение мне кажется наиболее логичным, т.к. я храню все объекты в HashMap и при работе с объектами из этой Map я могу описать разное поведение по `(... instanseof ParentSingleValue)` и по `(... instanseof ParentArrayValue)`

3 вариант мне не очень нравится т.к. он дает мне возможность узнать реализует ли объект интерфейс, но мне придется писать избыточный код реализации GetInId() и GetOutId() в каждом классе.

Может быть есть какие то еще варианты решения данной задачи, или в целом замечания по архитектуре? Возможно есть способы связывания объектов между собой без использования лишних полей, таких как in_id и out_id?

Язык Java.

Comment: 1-й точно нет. Теряешь метод в Parent. 3й и 4й вариант тоже являются примерами с достаточно избыточным кодом. Делать 2 класса ради такой мелочи не кажется менее избыточным. По опыту скажу что вариант номер 2 пользуется большей популярностью, так как его проще понять, проще с ним работать (не проверять же тип каждый раз). Что не маловажно. Но, если ты пишешь код только для себя и увидишь его только ты, тут можно намесить что угодно. Новых вариантов предложить не могу

Comment: вы можете попробовать использовать обобщения (generics), но в момент, когда вы от целого айдишника переходите к массиву, вам надо задуматься, возможно, вы решаете не ту задачу или не тем способом или что то ещё у вас пошло не так.

Comment: я бы выбрал вариант 2. Все остальное (если исходить из существующей постановке задачи) - overengineering.

Comment: второй вариант из перечисленных оптимальный. приводить объекты к классу родителю , чтобы потом проверять с помощью instanseof  кто есть кто - абсурд. зачем нам такой родитель, если полиморфизм не работает от слова совсем? вместе с тем, это не означает, что вариант  единственный. возможно, есть альтернативные архитектурные рещения, но нужно понимать, что такое in_id и out_id (как именно выполняется указанная связь объектов), иначе сложно что-то посоветовать